# Illegal Forward Reference and Enums

Tags: java, enums

I'm programming a game in java which is made up of a grid of tiles. I wan't to be able to inuitively define the edges of the tiles and how they relate to each other, e.g. to get the opposite edge of a tile, I want to be able to just type `TOP.opposite()`. However, when using enums to define these edges I end up having to forward reference at least two of them in the contstructor:

```
public enum Edge {

   TOP(Edge.BOTTOM), //illegal forward reference
   BOTTOM(Edge.TOP),
   LEFT(Edge.RIGHT), //illegal forward reference
   RIGHT(Edge.LEFT);

   private Edge opposite;

   private Edge(Edge opp){
      this.opposite = opp;
   }

   public Edge opposite(){
      return this.opposite;
   }
}
```

Is there any way of getting round this problem using enums which is just as simple?

Comment: For those who are curios about the source of this problem, I leave the link to [JSL doc section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) that explains why you may experience this.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can do this which is not as intuitive.

```
public enum Edge {
    TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT;
    private Edge opposite;

    static {
        TOP.opposite = BOTTOM;
        BOTTOM.opposite = TOP;
        LEFT.opposite = RIGHT;
        RIGHT.opposite = LEFT;
    }
    public Edge opposite(){
        return this.opposite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if the enum is needed in the static initializer of another class, then you can get the exception `class .....EnumName not an enum`. I will have to use Maps...

Comment: @P.Péter There should be no problem using an Enum anywhere in another class, static initializer or anywhere else.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You are right, I made another mistake which resulted in the mentioned exception. Your solution works just fine!

Comment: Different when the property is final and public.

Comment: @MattLBeck Is it guaranteed that reference on enum instance has already run the static block when client receives it? I suspect you are leaking not fully iniliazed enum instance. The line `TOP.opposite = BOTTOM` Just after that if client calls TOP.opposite.opposite you will get in some cases undefined behaviour.

Comment: * clients calls `Edge.TOP.opposite().opposite()`

Answer (score 27):

```
enum Edge {
    TOP {
        @Override
        public Edge opposite() {
            return BOTTOM;
        }
    },
    BOTTOM {
        @Override
        public Edge opposite() {
            return TOP;
        }
    },
    LEFT {
        @Override
        public Edge opposite() {
            return RIGHT;
        }
    },
    RIGHT {
        @Override
        public Edge opposite() {
            return LEFT;
        }
    };

    public abstract Edge opposite();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
public enum Edge {

    TOP,
    BOTTOM(Edge.TOP),
    LEFT,
    RIGHT(Edge.LEFT);

    private Edge opposite;

    private Edge() {

    }
    private Edge(Edge opp) {
        this.opposite = opp;
        opp.opposite = this;
    }

    public Edge opposite() {
        return this.opposite;
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes so much concise sense! We could even write TOP, LEFT first

Answer (score 11):

You can also make use of an *static innerclass* inside the enum:

```
public enum EnumTest     
{     
NORTH( Orientation.VERTICAL ),     
SOUTH( Orientation.VERTICAL ),     
EAST( Orientation.HORIZONTAL ),     
WEST( Orientation.HORIZONTAL );     

private static class Orientation  
{  
private static final String VERTICAL = null;     
private static final String HORIZONTAL = null;     
}
}
```

Stolen from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/547451/java/java/Enum-illegal-reference-compiles-Java) :)

Answer (score 9):

## Add a method `opposite` to return enum object

You could just define a method, `opposite()`.

### In modern Java, switch expression

In modern Java, we can use a [switch expression](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361). The compiler ensures that we have covered all possible cases.

```
enum Edge
{
    TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT;

    public Edge opposite ( )
    {
        return switch ( this )
                {
                    case TOP -> BOTTOM;
                    case BOTTOM -> TOP;
                    case LEFT -> RIGHT;
                    case RIGHT -> LEFT;
                };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println( Edge.TOP.opposite() );
```

> BOTTOM

### In earlier Java, `switch`

In older Java, use syntax seen in the following code.

Notice the need for a `default` case, in case you ever add an element to the enum or you inadvertently delete a case from the `switch`.

```
public enum Edge {
    TOP,
    BOTTOM,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT;

    public Edge opposite() {
        switch (this) {
            case TOP:
                return BOTTOM;
            case BOTTOM:
                return TOP;
            case LEFT:
                return RIGHT;
            case RIGHT:
                return LEFT;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Oh dear");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way

```
public enum Edge {

    TOP("BOTTOM"),
    BOTTOM("TOP"),
    LEFT("RIGHT"),
    RIGHT("LEFT");

    private String opposite;

    private Edge(String opposite){
        this.opposite = opposite;
    }

    public Edge opposite(){
        return valueOf(opposite);
    }

}
```

Peter Lawrey's solution is however more efficient and compiletime safe.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a static `Map` where key is the original enum and the value the opposite edge. Initialize it in a static block and the return the mapping from the `opposite()` method.

```
private static Map<Edge, Edge> oppostiteMapping;

static {
  oppositeMapping = new EnumMap<Edge, Edge>();
  oppositeMapping.put(TOP, BOTTOM);
  ...
}

public Edge opposite() {
    return oppositeMapping.get(this);
}
```

**EDIT:** as proposed in comment better to use EnumMap, so I upgraded accordingly

Btw. this approach is generally useful when you create something like static `fromString()` method etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an internal Map instead to define these associations. This works if at the point of initializing the Map, you already have all enum values created:

```
public enum Edge {

  TOP,
  BOTTOM,
  LEFT,
  RIGHT;

  private static final Map<Edge, Edge> opposites = 
        new EnumMap<Edge, Edge>(Edge.class);
  static {
    opposites.put(TOP, BOTTOM);
    opposites.put(BOTTOM, TOP);
    opposites.put(LEFT, RIGHT);
    opposites.put(RIGHT, LEFT);
  }

  public Edge opposite(){
    return opposites.get(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My method is by using ordinal. This is a simple example, but for a much more complex example see below.

```
public enum Edge {
    // Don't change the order! This class uses ordinal() in an arithmetic context.
    TOP,    // = 0
    LEFT,   // = 1
    RIGHT,  // = 2
    BOTTOM; // = 3

    public Edge other() {
        return values()[3 - ordinal()];
    }
}
```

Although using ordinal is discouraged for being fragile, using ordinal in the same enum as it's defined in is less fragile, and it's further mitigated here with a comment. Though the example above is quite trivial, the next example is less so. Compare the original way and the way using ordinal:

From 98 lines:

```
public enum Axes {
    NONE,
    HORIZONTAL,
    VERTICAL,
    BOTH;

    public Axes add(Axes axes) {
        switch (axes) {
            case HORIZONTAL:
                if (this == NONE)
                    return HORIZONTAL;
                if (this == VERTICAL)
                    return BOTH;
                break;
            case VERTICAL:
                if (this == NONE)
                    return VERTICAL;
                if (this == HORIZONTAL)
                    return BOTH;
                break;
            case BOTH:
                return BOTH;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError(axes);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Axes remove(Axes axes) {
        switch (axes) {
            case HORIZONTAL:
                if (this == HORIZONTAL)
                    return NONE;
                if (this == BOTH)
                    return VERTICAL;
                break;
            case VERTICAL:
                if (this == VERTICAL)
                    return NONE;
                if (this == BOTH)
                    return HORIZONTAL;
                break;
            case BOTH:
                return NONE;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError(axes);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Axes toggle(Axes axes) {
        switch (axes) {
            case NONE:
                return this;
            case HORIZONTAL:
                switch (this) {
                    case NONE:
                        return HORIZONTAL;
                    case HORIZONTAL:
                        return NONE;
                    case VERTICAL:
                        return BOTH;
                    case BOTH:
                        return VERTICAL;
                    default:
                        throw new AssertionError(axes);
                }
            case VERTICAL:
                switch (this) {
                    case NONE:
                        return VERTICAL;
                    case HORIZONTAL:
                        return BOTH;
                    case VERTICAL:
                        return NONE;
                    case BOTH:
                        return HORIZONTAL;
                    default:
                        throw new AssertionError(axes);
                }
            case BOTH:
                switch (this) {
                    case NONE:
                        return BOTH;
                    case HORIZONTAL:
                        return VERTICAL;
                    case VERTICAL:
                        return HORIZONTAL;
                    case BOTH:
                        return NONE;
                    default:
                        throw new AssertionError(axes);
                }
            default:
                throw new AssertionError(axes);
        }
    }
}
```

to 19 lines:

```
public enum Axes {
    // Don't change the order! This class uses ordinal() as a 2-bit bitmask.
    NONE,       // = 0 = 0b00
    HORIZONTAL, // = 1 = 0b01
    VERTICAL,   // = 2 = 0b10
    BOTH;       // = 3 = 0b11

    public Axes add(Axes axes) {
        return values()[ordinal() | axes.ordinal()];
    }

    public Axes remove(Axes axes) {
        return values()[ordinal() & ~axes.ordinal()];
    }

    public Axes toggle(Axes axes) {
        return values()[ordinal() ^ axes.ordinal()];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I preferred this:

```
public enum Edge {
   TOP,
   BOTTOM,
   LEFT,
   RIGHT;

   private Link link;

   private Link getLink() {
     if (link == null) {
        link = Link.valueOf(name());
     }
     return link;
   }

   public Edge opposite() {
      return getLink().opposite();
   }
}

public enum Link {
   TOP(Edge.BOTTOM),
   BOTTOM(Edge.TOP),
   LEFT(Edge.RIGHT),
   RIGHT(Edge.LEFT);

   private Edge opposite;

   private Link(Edge opp) {
      this.opposite = opp;
   }

   public Edge opposite() {
      return this.opposite;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 lambdas:

```
public enum Edge {
  TOP(() -> Edge.BOTTOM),
  BOTTOM(() -> Edge.TOP),
  LEFT(() -> Edge.RIGHT),
  RIGHT(() -> Edge.LEFT);

  private Supplier<Edge> opposite;

  private Edge(Supplier<Edge> opposite) {
    this.opposite = opposite;
  }

  public Edge opposite() {
    return opposite.get();
  }
}
```

Comment: While theoretically this makes sense and seems like a lacy way to solve the problem this still results in the compiler error "illegal forward reference"

Comment: I have to agree with @Spenhouet, I'm here because of the error showing up after using lambdas

Comment: But I've solved it by using the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608885/how-to-define-static-constants-in-a-java-enum