# How to define static constants in a Java enum?

Tags: java, enums, constants

Is there any way to define static final variables (effectively constants) in a Java enum declaration?

What I want is to define in one place the string literal value for the BAR(1...n) values:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum MyEnum {
    BAR1(BAR_VALUE),
    FOO("Foo"),
    BAR2(BAR_VALUE),
    ...,
    BARn(BAR_VALUE);

    private static final String BAR_VALUE = "Bar";

    @Getter
    private final String value;
}
```

I got the following error message for the code above: **Cannot reference a field before it is defined**.

Comment: why would you have so many enums with the same value? this seems totally against the idiom of enums!

Comment: Error text is answer for your problem !!

Comment: @Juvanis: notice that each enum instance has it own unique name so I don't consider it as a violation against the idioms of enums. In my case, instances of MyEnum acts as keys to a map which keys I want also to output to external target. These output values happens to be same in some cases according to the specification.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar: Nope, the answer is not there. I tried to put the constant declaration in first place, and I've got an another compilation error.

Comment: this works public enum MyEnum {
    BAR1(MyEnum.BAR_VALUE),
    FOO("Foo"),
    BAR2(MyEnum.BAR_VALUE),
    BARn(MyEnum.BAR_VALUE);

    private static final String BAR_VALUE = "Bar";

    private final String value;
    MyEnum(final String value){
        this.value =value;
    }
}

Comment: @jilt3d Interesting question, and the answers bellow are good, but why would you need to define these strings as constants? 
I don't see any benefit over using literals. Enums are unique instances so those strings are stored only once. There is no memory optimisation using static.

Comment: @Roland among possibly other reasons, [could be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608885/how-to-define-static-constants-in-a-java-enum#comment87383433_23609178) that there are Annotations that need to make static/constant references (by nature of Annotations in general).

Answer (score 112, accepted):

As IntelliJ IDEA suggest when extracting constant - make static nested class. This approach works:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum MyEnum {
    BAR1(Constants.BAR_VALUE),
    FOO("Foo"),
    BAR2(Constants.BAR_VALUE),
    ...,
    BARn(Constants.BAR_VALUE);



    @Getter
    private final String value;

    private static class Constants {
        public static final String BAR_VALUE = "BAR";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that the @RequiredArgsConstructor is from the lombok library.

Comment: Although this one does not working for using the 'constants' into annotations values.

Comment: @BrunoLeite This _does_ work for using the constants in annotation values if you make the `Constants` class non- `private`.

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @user207421 Static nested it is. Thanks :)

Answer (score 39):

```
public enum MyEnum {
    BAR1(MyEnum.BAR_VALUE);

    public static final String BAR_VALUE = "Bar";
```

works fine

Comment: I don't see any aspect that this answer adds to the existing and accepted answer. Could you please clarify your answer any further by providing a explanation?

Comment: @Snickbrack I do. It eliminates the static nested class. Good answer.

Comment: Could the upper case syntax  cause confusion between enum values and constants?

Comment: @borjab yes if you use that method, you can't have a constant and an enum with the same name

Comment: Do you have an explanation why this works? I am wondering why explicitly using `MyEnum` makes a difference, because implicitly it is already there.

Comment: Tried this and gives the same error: illegal forward reference in compilation time

Comment: Should fail during runtime!

Comment: @bit_cracker007, I've just tried this and it works. Great for using in annotations. At first thought, seems better than the accepted answer

Comment: @gillesB, if you don't use `MyEnum`, it gives you an `Illegal forward reference` error. I think that you need to call the constant as if from another place because if not, in practice you would be using an attribute from an object that doesn't exist yet, so you need to statically access that value "from outside".

Answer (score 7):

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.BAR3); // 10:BAR3
    }
}
enum MyEnum {
//  BAR1(       foo),   // error: illegal forward reference
//  BAR2(MyEnum.foo2),  // error: illegal forward reference
    BAR3(MyEnum.foo);   // no error

    int x;

    public static final int foo =10;
    public static       int foo2=20;
    MyEnum(int i) {x = i;}

    @Override public String toString() { return x+":"+super.toString(); }
}
```

This can be done without an inner class for the constant. And field initialization works as expected (in case you don't know, it *is* possible to read static fields before they are initialized, you will read the default 0 or null, but it does not happen here).