# Illegal forward reference in enum

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum and I'm trying to pass a final static variable as parameter in constructor. Problem is that first statement in enums has to be a instance itself, but in that case, final variable is not defined yet. See the code and you will understand:

```
public enum ParseResource {

    PUSH(API_URL); //Error: illegal forward reference

    private final static String API_URL = "https://api.parse.com/1";

    private String url;
    private ParseResource(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

and the other option:

```
public enum ParseResource {

    //Illegal in enums, first statement has to be an instance
    private final static String API_URL = "https://api.parse.com/1";

    PUSH(API_URL);

    private ParseResource(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: The solution that comes to mind is: don't have your url in a static field in your enum. Put it outside the enum or in your constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define static constants in a Java enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608885/how-to-define-static-constants-in-a-java-enum)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two possible solutions which seem reasonable to me.

1. Using a nested class (which is initialized separately):

   ```
   public enum ParseResource {
       PUSH(Constants.API_URL);

       private static class Constants {
           private static final String API_URL = "https://api.parse.com/1";
       }

       private String url;
       private ParseResource(String url) { this.url = url; }
   }
   ```

   That's the most generally useful, because it doesn't impose any important restrictions.
2. Using a method:

   ```
   public enum ParseResource {
       PUSH(getApiUrl());

       private static String getApiUrl() { return "https://api.parse.com/1"; }

       private String url;
       private ParseResource(String url) { this.url = url; }
   }
   ```

   One hidden downside to using a method is that a method invocation isn't a [*constant expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), so it can't be used for some things, like annotation element values.

---

There's also a 3rd possible way which works in practice, but as of Java 9 is *no longer guaranteed by the JLS to work*, so it shouldn't be used.

This used the qualified name `ParseResource.API_URL` instead of the simple name `API_URL` to circumvent the forward reference error, because `API_URL` is a [*constant variable*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) (i.e. initialized with a `String` literal in this case):

```
public enum ParseResource {
    PUSH(ParseResource.API_URL);

    private static final String API_URL = "https://api.parse.com/1";

    private String url;
    private ParseResource(String url) { this.url = url; }
}
```

In Java 8, the good behavior of this *was* specified by [8.3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2):

> Note that `static` fields that are constant variables are initialized before other `static` fields. [...] Such fields will never be observed to have their default initial values.

However, [due to this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168045), the wording was changed to the following [in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2):

> Note that `static` fields that are constant variables are initialized before other `static` fields. [...] **When such fields are referenced by simple name**, they will never be observed to have their default initial values.

The above code was not affected by the defect described in the bug report, but as of Java 9 it's no longer guaranteed to work.

Comment: Or just declare the static final constant directly before instance fields, and access it as a fully qualified constant. It strangely works ;-)

Comment: Is it no longer guaranteed to compile or no longer guaranteed that code compiled using that technique in java 8 will run on a java 9 runtime?

Comment: @Winter In Java 9 and above, `PUSH.url` might be `null` in that example, because `API_URL` might be assigned after the enum constant initializations.

Answer (score 0):

Enum are syntactic sugar that basically allow you to write nicer switch statements as well as iterate over a compile-time set of values of a certain class.

In this case you can define you compile-time string in a class like `Constants` - and the general rule when you face this kind of compile problems is that you should not use enum that way and need other classes

Comment: Yes, the presented example enum looks a bit odd, but I don't think your "general rule" exists. In a broader sense, regarding enums, there are a lot of more mechanics and use cases involved. Just take a closer look at  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you need to specify the class name:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.BAR3); // 10:BAR3
    }
}
enum MyEnum {
//  BAR1(       foo),   // error: illegal forward reference
//  BAR2(MyEnum.foo2),  // error: illegal forward reference
    BAR3(MyEnum.foo);   // no error

    int x;

    public static final int foo =10;
    public static       int foo2=20;
    MyEnum(int i) {x = i;}

    @Override public String toString() { return x+":"+super.toString(); }
}
```