# Java: Can I use a constant string as an enum key value?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum class with several key. 
A number of keys should have the same string value.
Sonar yells at me to replace the same string values with a constant value.

For example:

```
public enum MESSAGE_TYPES {

KEY1("Val1"),
KEY2("Val2"),
KEY3("Val3"),
KEY4("Val2"),
KEY5("Val4"),
KEY6("Val2"),
//etc.

}
```

So, sonar wants me to :

> Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal...

for "Val2" since it is defined 3 or more times. 
How can I achieve that?

Auto extracting the value to a constant puts it right after the enum keys, but then the value of the enum key doesn't recognize it of course.
So, I tried to put it on top of the enum class

```
public enum MESSAGE_TYPES {

    private static final String VAL2 = "Val2";

    KEY1("Val1"),
    KEY2(VAL2),
...
}
```

and so I get "Syntax error" errors on the line.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608885/how-to-define-static-constants-in-a-java-enum#23609178 i think this could help you :)

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming convents. enum CONSTANTS go uppercase, but the name of the enum class ... is just like an ordinary **class** name, thus it should be MessageTypes for example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot declare `static` fields in an enum class before declaring the enum values.
And declaring `static` fields after the enum values will not allow to use them in the enum constructor.
So just extract the `String` values in a  class and reference them in the enum values declaration.

For example :

```
public final class MyMessageConstant{

    public static final String VAL1 = "Val2";
    public static final String VAL2 = "Val2";

    private MyMessageConstant(){
    }
}
```

And the enum :

```
public enum MESSAGE_TYPES {

    KEY1(MyMessageConstant.VAL1),
    KEY2(MyMessageConstant.VAL2),
...
}
```

---

If it makes sense to keep the `String` values private to the enum class, you can declare the constant class as a `private static final` class member of the enum :

```
public enum Types {

    KEY1(MyMessageConstant.VAL1), KEY2(MyMessageConstant.VAL2),...
    KEY4(MyMessageConstant.VAL2),

    private static final class MyMessageConstant {        
       private static final String VAL1 = "Val2";
       private static final String VAL2 = "Val2";        
       private MyMessageConstant() {}
    }

    private String value;

    private Types(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I also have question related to enums [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956136/how-can-i-represent-key-with-list-of-values-for-each-environment-type-in-an-enum/). Wanted to see whether we can represent that easily with enums or not.

Comment: I did an answer as rather clear and nice question.