# Workaround for using enum type as field for same enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

What's the best workaround for the following situation:

```
public enum AnimalType {
   CAT(new AnimalType[] {}),
   DOG(new AnimalType[] {CAT, RAT}),
   BAT(new AnimalType[] {DOG}),
   PIG(new AnimalType[] {BAT, DOG}),
   RAT(new AnimalType[] {DOG, PIG}),
   ANT(new AnimalType[] {RAT});

   private final AnimalType[] afraidTypes;
   
   AnimalType(AnimalType[] afraidTypes) {
      this.afraidTypes = afraidTypes;
   }
}
```

The above code does not work because some fields are tried to be accessed before they are defined due to some cross-references like `DOG <---> RAT`.

I need the enum. What's the best way to add the `afraidTypes` as an array for each animal?

Comment: Why an enum? It seems like a solution in search of a problem--are you trying to make a rules engine?

Comment: You can use this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678309/illegal-forward-reference-and-enums which unfortunately doesn't guarantee at compile time that you have provided afraidTypes for all enum values.

Comment: I should have read all the answers -- you can declare a method on an enum which uses forward references.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal Forward Reference and Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678309/illegal-forward-reference-and-enums)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

As a workaround, use [switch expression](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361) to return a hard-coded set.

```java
enum Species
{
    CAT, DOG, BAT, PIG, RAT, ANT;

    public Set < Species > afraidOf ( )
    {
        return switch ( this )
                {
                    case CAT -> Set.of();
                    case DOG -> Set.of( CAT , RAT );
                    case BAT -> Set.of( DOG );
                    case PIG -> Set.of( BAT , DOG );
                    case RAT -> Set.of( DOG , PIG );
                    case ANT -> Set.of( RAT );
                };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println( Species.DOG.afraidOf() );
```

> [CAT, RAT]

## Details

This was an interesting bit of Java.

Seems you *can* pass elements of an enum to a constructor of that same enum. Like this, for example:

```java
package work.basil.animal;

import java.util.Set;

public class App3
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        enum Species
        {
            CAT( Set.of() ),
            DOG( Set.of( CAT ) ),
            BAT( Set.of( DOG ) ),
            PIG( Set.of( BAT , DOG ) ),
            RAT( Set.of( DOG , PIG ) ),
            ANT( Set.of( RAT ) );

            Set < Species > afraidOf;

            Species ( Set < Species > afraidOf )
            {
                this.afraidOf = afraidOf;
            }
        }

        System.out.println( Species.DOG.afraidOf );
    }
}
```

### *Illegal forward references* error

But you cannot make a “forward reference”. So we cannot fulfill your desire to make dogs afraid of rats, because when the dog’s constructor is run, the `RAT` instance has not yet been created.

So the following code fails:

```java
            CAT( Set.of() ),
            DOG( Set.of( CAT , RAT ) ),  // <--- Error: Illegal forward reference.
            BAT( Set.of( DOG ) ),
            PIG( Set.of( BAT , DOG ) ),
            RAT( Set.of( DOG , PIG ) ),
            ANT( Set.of( RAT ) );
```

### Workaround: Hard-code using switch expression

One workaround is to add a method `afraidOf` that returns a set (or array, whatever). Use [switch expression](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361) for compact code.

```java
package work.basil.animal;

import java.util.Set;

public class App3
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        enum Species
        {
            CAT, DOG, BAT, PIG, RAT, ANT;

            public Set < Species > afraidOf ( )
            {
                return switch ( this )
                        {
                            case CAT -> Set.of();
                            case DOG -> Set.of( CAT , RAT );
                            case BAT -> Set.of( DOG );
                            case PIG -> Set.of( BAT , DOG );
                            case RAT -> Set.of( DOG , PIG );
                            case ANT -> Set.of( RAT );
                            default -> Set.of();  // Or throw an exception here, your choice.
                        };
            }
        }

        System.out.println( Species.DOG.afraidOf() );
    }
}
```

> [CAT, RAT]

#### Compiler checks for all cases

You IDE may point out to you that the `default` case is unnecessary in modern Java.

If you add a new element to the enum like `COW`, or you delete a case from the switch expression, the compiler alerts you with the error “'switch' expression does not cover all possible input values”.

So the following suffices for safe code. We can rest assured we have covered all the cases.

```java
                return switch ( this )
                        {
                            case CAT -> Set.of();
                            case DOG -> Set.of( CAT , RAT );
                            case BAT -> Set.of( DOG );
                            case PIG -> Set.of( BAT , DOG );
                            case RAT -> Set.of( DOG , PIG );
                            case ANT -> Set.of( RAT );
                        };
```

#### `EnumSet`

The `EnumSet` class is a specialized implementation of `Set`, optimized for enum objects. An `EnumSet` is extremely efficient, taking little memory and executing quite quickly.

You can optimize our solution by using [`EnumSet.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#of(E,E)) rather than [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E,E)). But be aware that in some implementations of Java, the `Set.of` method may be smart enough to make this optimization on its own and return an `EnumSet` as its `Set` object.

```java
                return switch ( this )
                        {
                            case CAT -> EnumSet.noneOf( Species.class );
                            case DOG -> EnumSet.of( CAT , RAT );
                            case BAT -> EnumSet.of( DOG );
                            case PIG -> EnumSet.of( BAT , DOG );
                            case RAT -> EnumSet.of( DOG , PIG );
                            case ANT -> EnumSet.of( RAT );
                        };
```

An `EnumSet` is modifiable. So if you want [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable), stick with using `Set.of`.

---

I used `Set` here, as that is my own preference. But if you insist, I expect you could use this same code with mere arrays.

Comment: I would make default throw an exception, and have a unit test which exercised `afraidOf` for each value in the enum.

Comment: @tgdavies No need; the compiler checks for all cases being covered. I just revised the Answer with that info. I guess this behavior is part of the "pattern matching" features added in recent versions of Java.

Comment: So it does! TIL

Comment: I added the modern syntax of switch expressions seen here to [this existing similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678363/642706) on the [original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5678309/642706).

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149764/11002 suggests:

```java
public class App {

    public enum AnimalType {
        CAT {
            public AnimalType[] getAfraidOf() {
                return new AnimalType[] { DOG };
            }
        },
        DOG {
            public AnimalType[] getAfraidOf() {
                return new AnimalType[] { CAT };
            }
        };


        public abstract AnimalType[] getAfraidOf();
    }
}
```

Which while verbose, guarantees that when you add a new value to the enum you can't forget to provide the attribute.